# Trying to use ffmpeg to create slideshow from ISO-8601 named pictures. Getting output with no playable streams

Tags: image, ffmpeg, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow of images that are irregular in dimension/orientation but all named with the same ISO-8601 date format.

I've normalized the filenames so they are all YYYYMMDD.jpg. I have tried using the globular pattern type for ffmpeg and various methods for inputting the files, including piping the concatenation of the files into ffmpeg.

Here are the images I'm trying to use:

```sh
$ ls *.jpg | xargs -n1 file
20190411.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=upper-left, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10128x3984, components 3
20190417.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10176x3952, components 3
20190424.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=upper-left, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 12128x3840, components 3
20190429.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=upper-left, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 11104x3888, components 3
20190430.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10992x3920, components 3
20190501.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10528x3936, components 3
20190502.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10992x3792, components 3
20190508.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 11008x3808, components 3
20190515.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10416x3760, components 3
20190516.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10928x3760, components 3
20190517.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=lower-right, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 10720x3840, components 3
20190522.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6552x1688, components 3
20190523.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6572x1700, components 3
20190524.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6468x1659, components 3
20190528.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 5424x1644, components 3
20190529.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=7, model=Pixel 2 XL, height=0, manufacturer=Google, orientation=[*0*], datetime=2019:05:29 16:38:01, width=0]
20190531.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6584x1693, components 3
20190603.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6536x1690, components 3
20190604.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 5748x1618, components 3
20190606.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6196x1690, components 3
20190607.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6112x1674, components 3
20190610.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6440x1670, components 3
20190611.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6312x1694, components 3
20190612.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, height=0, orientation=[*0*], width=0], baseline, precision 8, 6176x1689, components 3
```

And these are the various ffmpeg commands I've tried using:

```sh
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

```sh
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output.mkv
```

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' out.mp4
```

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I'm trying to create a video that shows each image for 5 seconds in order, but I'm getting a mp4 video file with no playable streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such big width x height will be difficult to decode. Try adding the scale filter to deal with the various image dimensions and to make a more playable output size.

You can pad the difference:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -r 25 out.mp4
```

or crop:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase:eval=frame,crop=1920:1080,setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -r 25 out.mp4
```

Comment: This is needed for *some* players, not for those which use libavcodec, like Potplayer and VLC.

Comment: @Gyan We have no idea what player is being used, and I imagine it will be watched scaled to fit a display anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1/5 -i - -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`